# scipy.sparse.coo_matrix how to fast find all zeros column, fill with 1 and normalize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

For a matrix, i want to find columns with all zeros and fill with 1s, and then normalize the matrix by column. I know how to do that with np.arrays

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]      
     |
     V
[[0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0]    
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0]]
     |
     V
[[0   0.2 0 0 0]
 [0   0.2 1 0 0]
 [0.5 0.2 0 1 0]   
 [0   0.2 0 0 1]
 [0.5 0.2 0 0 0]]
```

But how can I do the same thing when the matrix is in scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix form, without converting it back to np.arrays. how can I achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a lot easier with the `lil` format, and working with rows rather than columns:

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
In [2]: A=np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0]])
In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [4]: At=A.T                # switch to work with rows

In [5]: M=sparse.lil_matrix(At)
```

Now it is obvious which row is all zeros

```
In [6]: M.data
Out[6]: array([[1, 1], [], [1], [1], [1]], dtype=object)
In [7]: M.rows
Out[7]: array([[2, 4], [], [1], [2], [3]], dtype=object)
```

And `lil` format allows us to fill that row:

```
In [8]: M.data[1]=[1,1,1,1,1]
In [9]: M.rows[1]=[0,1,2,3,4]
In [10]: M.A
Out[10]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

I could have also used `M[1,:]=np.ones(5,int)`

The `coo` format is great for creating the array from the `data/row/col` arrays, but doesn't implement indexing or math.  It has to be transformed to `csr` for that.  And `csc` for column oriented stuff.

The row that I filled isn't so obvious in the csr format:

```
In [14]: Mc=M.tocsr()
In [15]: Mc.data
Out[15]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [16]: Mc.indices
Out[16]: array([2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [17]: Mc.indptr
Out[17]: array([ 0,  2,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int32)
```

On the other hand normalizing is probably easier in this format.

```
In [18]: Mc.sum(axis=1)
Out[18]: 
matrix([[2],
        [5],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1]], dtype=int32)
In [19]: Mc/Mc.sum(axis=1)
Out[19]: 
matrix([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
        [ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2],
        [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ]])
```

Notice that it's converted the sparse matrix to a dense one.  The `sum` is dense, and math involving sparse and dense usually produces dense.

I have to use a more round about calculation to preserve the sparse status:

```
In [27]: Mc.multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(1/Mc.sum(axis=1)))
Out[27]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Here's a way of doing this with the `csc` format (on `A`)

```
In [40]: Ms=sparse.csc_matrix(A)
In [41]: Ms.sum(axis=0)
Out[41]: matrix([[2, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Use `sum` to find the all-zeros column.  Obviously this could be wrong if the columns have negative values and happen to sum to 0.  If that's a concern I can see making a copy of the matrix with all `data` values replaced by 1.

```
In [43]: Ms[:,1]=np.ones(5,int)[:,None]
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csc_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
In [44]: Ms.A
Out[44]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The warning matters more if you do this sort of change repeatedly.  Notice I have to adjust the dimension of the LHS array.  Depending on the number of all-zero columns this action can change the sparsity of the matrix substantially.

==================

I could search the `col` of `coo` format for missing values with:

```
In [69]: Mo=sparse.coo_matrix(A)
In [70]: Mo.col
Out[70]: array([2, 0, 3, 4, 0], dtype=int32)

In [71]: Mo.col==np.arange(Mo.shape[1])[:,None]
Out[71]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [72]: idx = np.nonzero(~(Mo.col==np.arange(Mo.shape[1])[:,None]).any(axis=1))[0]
In [73]: idx
Out[73]: array([1], dtype=int32)
```

I could then add a column of 1s at this `idx` with:

```
In [75]: N=Mo.shape[0]
In [76]: data = np.concatenate([Mo.data, np.ones(N,int)])
In [77]: row = np.concatenate([Mo.row, np.arange(N)])
In [78]: col = np.concatenate([Mo.col, np.ones(N,int)*idx])
In [79]: Mo1 = sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row, col)), shape=Mo.shape)
In [80]: Mo1.A
Out[80]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

As written it works for just one column, but it could be generalized to several.  I also created a new matrix rather than update `Mo`.  But this in-place seems to work as well:

```
Mo.data,Mo.col,Mo.row = data,col,row
```

The normalization still requires `csr` conversion, though I think `sparse` can hide that for you.

```
In [87]: Mo1/Mo1.sum(axis=0)
Out[87]: 
matrix([[ 0. ,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.2,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0.5,  0.2,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ],
        [ 0.5,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

Even when I take the extra work of maintaining the sparse nature, I still get a `csr` matrix:

```
In [89]: Mo1.multiply(sparse.coo_matrix(1/Mo1.sum(axis=0)))
Out[89]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

See

[Find all-zero columns in pandas sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711838/find-all-zero-columns-in-pandas-sparse-matrix)

for more methods of finding the 0 columns.  It turns out `Mo.col==np.arange(Mo.shape[1])[:,None]` is too slow with large `Mo`.  A test using `np.in1d` is much better.

```
1 - np.in1d(np.arange(Mo.shape[1]),Mo.col)
```

Comment: OK, I've added a `coo` version.