# Split sparse matrice in coo format by column

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have stored my dataset in a sparse matrice in coo format. I have approximately 4 milion feature. Is there a way for split it and take the first n columns?

Comment: convert to `csc` and slice.  `coo` does not implement indexing.

Comment: You could also work directly with the `.col` attribute, as I demonstrate toward the end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/39684081/901925