# Find all-zero columns in pandas sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

For example I have a coo_matrix A :

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
A = sp.coo_matrix([3,0,3,0],
                  [0,0,2,0],
                  [2,5,1,0],
                  [0,0,0,0])
```

How can I get result [0,0,0,1], which indicates that first 3 columns contain non-zero values, only the 4th column is all zeros.

PS : cannot convert A to other type.
PS2 : I tried using `np.nonzeros` but it seems that my implementation is not very elegant.

Comment: By `other type` do you mean other sparse formats, or just types like `numpy` array?

Comment: @hpaulj I meant just coo_matrix

Comment: As I note in my answer, solutions might involve a format conversion under the cover.  Sparse functions freely convert format to suit the calculation needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1** We could do something like this -

```
# Get the columns indices of the input sparse matrix
C = sp.find(A)[1]

# Use np.in1d to create a mask of non-zero columns. 
# So, we invert it and convert to int dtype for desired output.
out = (~np.in1d(np.arange(A.shape[1]),C)).astype(int)
```

Alternatively, to make the code shorter, we can use subtraction -

```
out = 1-np.in1d(np.arange(A.shape[1]),C)
```

Step-by-step run -

1) Input array and sparse matrix from it :

```
In [137]: arr             # Regular dense array
Out[137]: 
array([[3, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 5, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [138]: A = sp.coo_matrix(arr) # Convert to sparse matrix as input here on
```

2) Get non-zero column indices :

```
In [139]: C = sp.find(A)[1]

In [140]: C
Out[140]: array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

3) Use `np.in1d` to get mask of non-zero columns :

```
In [141]: np.in1d(np.arange(A.shape[1]),C)
Out[141]: array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

4) Invert it :

```
In [142]: ~np.in1d(np.arange(A.shape[1]),C)
Out[142]: array([False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

5) Finally convert to int dtype :

```
In [143]: (~np.in1d(np.arange(A.shape[1]),C)).astype(int)
Out[143]: array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Alternative subtraction approach :

```
In [145]: 1-np.in1d(np.arange(A.shape[1]),C)
Out[145]: array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

**Approach #2** Here's another way and possibly a faster one using `matrix-multiplication` -

```
out = 1-np.ones(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)*A.astype(bool)
```

---

**Runtime test**

Let's test out all the posted approaches on a big and really sparse matrix -

```
In [29]: A = sp.coo_matrix((np.random.rand(4000,4000)>0.998).astype(int))

In [30]: %timeit 1-np.in1d(np.arange(A.shape[1]),sp.find(A)[1])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.12 ms per loop # Approach1

In [31]: %timeit 1-np.ones(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)*A.astype(bool)
1000 loops, best of 3: 771 µs per loop # Approach2

In [32]: %timeit 1 - (A.col==np.arange(A.shape[1])[:,None]).any(axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 236 ms per loop # @hpaulj's soln

In [33]: %timeit (A!=0).sum(axis=0)==0
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop  # @jez's soln

In [34]: %timeit (np.sum(np.absolute(A.toarray()), 0) == 0) * 1
10 loops, best of 3: 86.4 ms per loop  # @wwii's soln
```

Comment: With a test array like this it is very unlikely that there will be any all 0 columns.  It's not sparse at all, only 1/3 are zero.  `sparse.random(1000,1000)` is much sparser but still might not have such columns.  But it doesn't seem to change the time rankings.

Comment: @hpaulj True. So, one can use : `sp.coo_matrix((np.random.rand(1000,1000)>0.998).astype(int))`, but as speculated, the speedup won't change by a big factor.

Answer (score 1):

The actual logical operation can be performed like this:

```
b = (A!=0).sum(axis=0)==0
# matrix([[False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Now, to ensure that I'm answering your question exactly, I'd better tell you how you *could* convert from booleans to integers (although really, for most applications I can think of, you can do a lot more in `numpy` and friends if you stick with an array of `bool`s):

```
b = b.astype(int)
#matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Either way, to then convert from a `matrix` to a `list`, you could do this:

```
c = list(b.flat)
# [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

...although again, I'm not sure this is the best thing to do: for most applications I can imagine, I would perhaps just convert to a one-dimensional `numpy.array` with `c = b.A.flatten()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Recent

[scipy.sparse.coo_matrix how to fast find all zeros column, fill with 1 and normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683931/scipy-sparse-coo-matrix-how-to-fast-find-all-zeros-column-fill-with-1-and-norma)

similar, except it wants to fill those columns with 1s and normalize them.

I immediately suggested the `lil` format of the transpose.  All-0 columns will be empty lists in this format.  But sticking with the `coo` format I suggested

```
np.nonzero(~(Mo.col==np.arange(Mo.shape[1])[:,None]).any(axis=1))[0]
```

or for this 1/0 format

```
1 - (Mo.col==np.arange(Mo.shape[1])[:,None]).any(axis=1)
```

which is functionally the same as:

```
1 - np.in1d(np.arange(Mo.shape[1]),Mo.col)
```

`sparse.find` converts the matrix to `csr` to sum duplicates and eliminate duplicates, and then back to `coo` to get the `data`, `row`, and `col` attributes (which it returns).

`Mo.nonzero` uses `A.data != 0` to eliminate 0s before returning the `col` and `row` attributes.

The `np.ones(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)*A.astype(bool)` solution requires converting `A` to `csr` format for multiplication.

`(A!=0).sum(axis=0)` also converts to `csr` because column (or row) sum is done with a matrix multiplication.

So the no-convert requirement is unrealistic, at least within the bounds of sparse formats.

===============

For Divakar's test case my `==` version is quite slow; it's ok with small ones, but creates too large of test array with the 1000 columns.

Testing on a matrix that is sparse enough to have a number of 0 columns:

```
In [183]: Arr=sparse.random(1000,1000,.001)
In [184]: (1-np.in1d(np.arange(Arr.shape[1]),Arr.col)).any()
Out[184]: True
In [185]: (1-np.in1d(np.arange(Arr.shape[1]),Arr.col)).sum()
Out[185]: 367

In [186]: timeit 1-np.ones(Arr.shape[0],dtype=bool)*Arr.astype(bool)
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop
In [187]: timeit 1-np.in1d(np.arange(Arr.shape[1]),Arr.col)
1000 loops, best of 3: 323 µs per loop
In [188]: timeit 1-(Arr.col==np.arange(Arr.shape[1])[:,None]).any(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.9 ms per loop
In [189]: timeit (Arr!=0).sum(axis=0)==0
1000 loops, best of 3: 820 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarking, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to an array or dense matrix, sum the absolute value along the first axis, test the result against zero, convert to int

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> (np.sum(np.absolute(a.toarray()), 0) == 0) * 1
array([0, 0, 0, 1])
>>> (np.sum(np.absolute(a.todense()), 0) == 0) * 1
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 1]])
>>> 
>>> np.asarray((np.sum(np.absolute(a.todense()), 0) == 0), dtype = np.int32)
array([[0, 0, 0, 1]])
>>>
```

---

The first is the fastest - 24 uS for your example on my machine.

For a matrix made with `np.random.randint(0,3,(1000,1000))`, all are right at 25 mS on my machine.